# Question about Sound Formats

Tags: recording

so there seems to be a lot of different sound formats out there youtube is using 5.1. and there's also 6.11 7.1 10.2. with all these sound formats do you need to pay special action when you recording?

Comment: So is this question about how to record a track so that it takes advantage of (say) 5.1 surround?

Comment: Since most people are going to be listening to the likes of youtube on headphones, the simple left and right channels are already avaiable. Most recording by the man in the street are in that format.

Answer (score 2):

No. You don’t *need* to do anything. You can mix to stereo and everyone can play back stereo.

If you want to produce content that takes advantage of the capabilities of any surround formats, then you have an overwhelming array of options on how you do that.

The simplest is to just record a bunch of mono sources and then mix them together with a surround mixer with surround monitoring and then author the mix with the appropriate encoding(s) for the format(s) you want to deliver in.

If you want, you can always record sources with two or more mics and then mix them appropriately as above, which you can also do with a stereo mix.

In the end, the choices and mixing processes are all essentially the same as when you want the final mix to be stereo, it’s just the cost and complexity of both the mixing software and hardware and the mixing process can increase a lot as you add more surround channels.

Comment: thank you so basically  it will still be good even if i dont do anything. But if i want it even better i need to further research right?

Comment: @doodlerdoodle I don't know what you mean by "good" or "better". If you want to mix surround sound, you need mixing software or hardware that has surround panning and then you need to have a surround monitoring system. Since it's unlikely anyone is going to have a surround sound music listening setup, it's normally not worth it unless you're mixing sound for film. Think about how many people listen to music on headphones. Surround mixing is expensive to set up and then most people won't even notice it. I'd forget about it.